# Parallel ForEach on singleton's storage fields

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, singleton

I have a metrics storage implemented with this singleton pattern:

```
// Thread-safe 'Lazy' singleton for metrics collection
public sealed class MetricsService
{
    private static readonly MetricsService instance = new MetricsService();

    static MetricsService()
    {
    }

    private MetricsService()
    {
        Storage = new List<DeviceMetrics>();

        Requests = new List<RequestMetrics>();
        Subruns = new List<SubrunMetrics>();
        Runs = new List<RunMetrics>();
    }

    public static MetricsService Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
    //
```

and it has some methods like this one:

```
    // Get metrics for a single component in specific device
    public List<SubrunMetrics> GetComponentMetrics(string deviceName, string componentName)
    {
        var device = GetDeviceMetrics(deviceName);

        if (device != null)
        {
            // get list of subruns
            var subrunsList = new List<SubrunMetrics>();

            foreach (var run in device.RunMetrics)
            {
                run.SubrunMetrics.ForEach(subrunsList.Add);
            }

            // generate new list of subruns related to component
            var results = new List<SubrunMetrics>();

            foreach (var subrun in subrunsList)
            {
                if (subrun.ComponentName == componentName)
                {
                    results.Add(subrun);
                }
            }

            if (results.Count > 0)
            {
                return results;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
    //
```

Now, I was wondering if multi-threading could be used here, let's assume in this kind of way:

```
        ...

        if (device != null)
        {
            // get list of subruns
            var subrunsList = new List<SubrunMetrics>();

            Parallel.ForEach(device.RunMetrics, (run) =>
                                                {
                                                    run.SubrunMetrics.ForEach(subrunsList.Add);
                                                }
                            );

            // generate new list of subruns related to component
            var results = new List<SubrunMetrics>();

            Parallel.ForEach(subrunsList, (subrun) =>
                                          {
                                              results.Add(subrun);
                                          }
                            );
```

I've read some materials at MSDN about this but I'm still not sure if this thread-safety lazy thing makes it safe for real and then will it gain speed?

Comment: If you are modifying instance fields/properties, then no, it's not thread-safe. However, I see no reason for those parallel loops

Comment: As just one example - `run.SubrunMetrics.ForEach(subrunsList.Add)` is not thread-safe, since two threads will be potentially calling `subrunsList.Add` at the same time. And `List<T>` is not thread-safe in that scenario.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Thread Safe Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/) to make it a viable thread safe solution, but whether it will be quicker or not depends on the number of items. It it is a large number I am sure you can save significant amount of time.